# How to get all the referenced syntax trees for a given syntax tree

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I need to get all the syntax trees that referenced to a given syntax tree.

**Following is my use case:**

User selected the Class1.cs which has a reference from Class2.cs,Class3.cs,...

**Requirement:**

I need to get all the syntax trees which are referenced by the selected class (Class1.cs)

Comment: How do you define "referenced"?

Comment: @SLaks: My goal here is to compile the Class1.cs and emit the assembly for that particular class, I tried emit with the semantic model of Class1.cs and failed, compilation result says its unable to find referenced classes.

Comment: You need to give roslyn all references to compile everyting. It can't magically find all references.